# when i select other form droplist then i want appear one textbox

Tags: html, django

Hi i have a list of industry in that there is a option other when i click on other then the textbox for other will be appear . i don't understand how to do this i have tried the djangoajax but not worked

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 "  style = "position:relative; left:180px; top:20px; ">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">  Sector </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            {{  form.industry  }}
                            <span class="help-block"> {{ form.industry.errors }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style = "top:20px; ">   Others </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8" style = "top:20px; ">
                                <!--{{ form.other }}--><input type="test" style="width: 350px;"  id="model1234" >
                                <span class="help-block">{{ form.other.errors }}</span>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achiveve this with jQuery. I adapted your code a bit.

```js
$('#my_select select').change(function(){
  var option_selected = $('#my_select select option:selected').text();
  if(option_selected == 'Other'){
    $('#others_div').show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-5 "  style = "position:relative; left:180px; top:20px; ">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">  Sector </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8" id="my_select">
            <select >
              <option selected>Option 1</option>
              <option>Other</option>
            </select>
            <span class="help-block"> {{ form.industry.errors }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="others_div" style="display:none;">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" style = "top:20px; "> 
            Others 
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8" style = "top:20px; ">
                <input type="test" style="width: 350px;"  id="model1234" >
                <span class="help-block">{{ form.other.errors }}</span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```